# Loading module external page Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, module

I am trying to load a module on an external page from the Joomla core.

I am using the following:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).'/../../..' );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('xxxx', 'xxxxxxx');
$memberships = JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
```

But get the following error

JPath::check Use of relative paths not permitted

Any ideas

Comment: Try replacing this `dirname(__FILE__).'/../../..' )` with `dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))`

Comment: can you just give the path of your module from joomla installation ?

Comment: @DaveJust , nice stuff, worked perfectly, thanks... can you put as answer so I can mark as correct thanks.